# AWS Storage Gateway on EC2 needs HTTP server?

Tags: apache-http-server, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to deploy an AWS File Gateway to an EC2 instance (as a test before looking into the hardware appliance). There's a webpage guide [here](https://us-east-2.console.aws.amazon.com/storagegateway) which I believe to be insufficient.

As an unsafe test, I've created an EC2 instance (running Amazon Linux on m4.xlarge) with all inbound and outbound traffic allowed. My instance has an internet gateway and a public IPv4 address. I can ping and SSH into my instance.

The fourth step of that guide asks for my instance IP, which when I supply, results in a "CONNECTION REFUSED" page. It tries to connect me via HTTP to:

```
http://[instance_IP]/?gatewayType=FILE_S3&activationRegion=us-east-2
```

This surprised me, since there are no instructions about launching a HTTP server.

As a quick test, I launched a HTTP server on the instance via:

```
sudo yum install -y httpd
sudo service httpd start
```

Now that URL directs me to a generic Apache test page.

It seems like the AWS File Gateway guide assumes that the EC2 instance will come prepared with a server setup to handle file gateway activation. But this clearly isn't the case, nor is there any documentation alluding to this.
Clearly there's a gap in the guide page, and possibly there are prepared instances for launching File Gateways. What are the missing steps?

Answer (score 1):

Per the guide [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/latest/userguide/ec2-gateway-file.html), when you select the host platform for EC2 instance, you get a "Launch instance" option

[image]

This provisions a new instance based on a AMI name starting with "aws-storage-gateway".

[image]

The AMI id will vary based on the region and date of the build.

[image]

This AMI has all the necessary software required to connect and activate the storage gateway.

If you skip with the launch instance option and select an EC2 instance which was previously provisioned, it will expect that there is some sort of service on instance to activate the storage gateway.

Comment: My question is precisely about 'tieing the IP' failing, due to Amazon's guide page trying to connect via HTTP

Comment: Did you choose to create a new instance or select an existing instance when setting up the storage gateway?

Comment: There are no such options - follow the link and try. At "select host platform", I select the Amazon EC2 option and follow its instructions (in the bottom dropdown box) for creating a new EC2 instance. No step prepares the instance with a HTTP server.

Comment: There's mention of an AMI [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/latest/userguide/create-gateway-file.html#ec2-gateway-file) which I can't find anywhere in the dev console.

Comment: I followed the steps to use EC2 host for storage gateway, selected new EC2 instance and got it provisioned and activated without any errors. The AMI name starts with `aws-storage-gateway` and the AMI id varies based on the region.